# How does Christy Lee Rogers take these photographs?

Tags: technique, artwork

[Christy Lee Rogers](http://www.christyrogers.com/home.html) is an artist/photographer. I find her work surreal. Below are couple of photographs she took "straight out the camera".

**Any idea how these photographs might be taken ?**

[image]

Another image here. You can check out the gallery over [here](http://www.christyrogers.com/collect9/101.html)

[image]

Comment: Can you link to larger versions of the images please? It's hard to tell exactly what's going on at this size, though it looks like they are shot looking down through the surface of the water.

Comment: @NickMiners You can google her name. There are plenty of images on the internet. Here is the link :- https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=christy+lee+rogers+photography&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.b2I&biw=1440&bih=765&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=1wIBUcvkJsXZ2QXbh4G4Cw

Comment: @VinothKumar - sending people who want to help you to Google is a little bit rude - especially wen the answer to your question can be found on Google

Comment: @Nir Link to her site was in the question itself, guess both of you overlooked, lol.

Comment: The link to the site was there, but not the specific images. There is no way to easily find these images on her site without hunting through all her galleries.

Comment: @Nir. I'm sorry; I did not mean to be rude. I just thought that is the easiest way to find her images :)

Answer (score 18):

A quick Google search for "Christy Lee Rogers making of" returns enough information:

- The pictures are taken underwater
- From [this interview](http://astrumpeople.com/christy-lee-rogers-amazing-underwater-water-photography/)

> The effects in my images are created naturally in-camera using the
>   refraction of light and movement in different depths of water.  Light
>   has a lower optical density in the air, while light traveling in water
>   has a higher optical density, causing a bending of light and the
>   captured image while bodies are immersed in water.

- From [this post](http://www.petapixel.com/2012/09/14/underwater-photos-that-mimic-the-look-of-baroque-paintings/) -- Rogers creates her photos in swimming pools at night. The scenes are illuminated with bright off-camera lights

There's also more information in [this PDF](http://www.christyrogers.com/assets/Rogers_030711B.pdf) on Christy Lee Rogers's own site

Comment: Light does not have a property called "optical density" (here, also "refractive index").  Material through which light travels does.  Water has a higher refractive index than air. When light passes through the transition of two materials of different RIs, it is refracted, or bent.  This is how lenses work. The rippling effect in the photos is caused by the air to water change in RI.  "Optical density" usually refers to the absorbance of a material but can refer to RI as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [short bio](http://www.christyrogers.com/bio.html) on her web site summarizes:

> Without the use of post-production manipulation, her works are made
>   in-camera, on the spot, in water and at night.